# Custom CSS stylesheet in SharePoint 2019 on-premise

Tags: css, sharepoint-on-prem, custom-masterpage, 2019, homepage

I have site pages like Home.aspx, Contact.aspx in SP 2019 on premise. How to apply custom CSS stylesheet to those pages? I have added Override.css to the seattle.master page which is my current master page, but the custom file does not load. This does not seem to work at all. How to make sure to link the custom stylesheet to the Home.aspx and other site pages? Thanks

None of these worked

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="_catalogs/masterpage/Override.css" After="corev15.css" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="https://one.echristus.net/sites/test-TFS/Style%20Library/Override.css" runat="server"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://one.echristus.net/sites/test-TFS/Style%20Library/Override.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_catalogs/masterpage/Override.css" />
```

Comment: You need to add details like what script tags you are using in your master page and what process did you follow when doing the changes/creating the masterpage.

Comment: <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/_catalogs/masterpage/cusTheme/cus.css" runat="server" after="corev15.css" /> Works for me in 2013/2016. Are you sure that it's nothing that is getting cached? Are you using minimal download strategy? Have you made sure that you published your masterpage as a major version after doing the changes?

Comment: Yes @Christoffer I have published my masterpage's major version. The CSS file is not even loading in the Home page. I need to look for minimal download strategy though. Any idea on how to overcome minimal download strategy? I am currently referring to MS official documentation over that topic. Thanks

Comment: Are you using modern or classic layout for your sites?

Comment: Its the modern layout @Christoffer

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint:AjaxDelta container for loading components in MDS mode. Please try this.
Resources:
[MSDN MDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/modify-sharepoint-components-for-mds)
[Optimize page performance in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/optimize-page-performance-in-sharepoint)

If you use Modern pages you need create custom actions in SPFX.